# Set height of v.TexaArea of ipyvuetify to a single row and expandable

Tags: ipywidgets, ipyvuetify

The default height of v.Textarea seems to be ~8 rows. In order to save space in UI, can we reduce it to a single row, and make it expandable in height upon users typing.

```py
import ipyvuetify as v
my_text_box = v.Textarea(
    label= "My note",
    background_color="#FAFABF",
    v_model= 'I have typed some text')

my_text_box
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by setting `rows = 1` and `auto_grow = True`. Closing this question.